# Convert issue mm to pixel in Android

Tags: java, android

I've tried to make a 30mmx10mm-size linear layout as follows.

```
LinearLayout llBody = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_body);
float width, height;
width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = llBody.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = (int) width;
layoutParams.height = (int) height;
llBody.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But as a result, I've got a little magnified LinearLayout.

I logged width and I got 625 pixels.

And the dpi of the device is 420.

I tried to calculate manually, I got 37.797619048 mm.

I can't find the reason and any solutions.

I used Nexus 5X API 29 (x86) Emulator in Android Studio 3.5.3.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it manually,

- in case of adding Width and Height hardCoded in XML [image: XML]
- and the way you tried: [image: your way]

neigher I don't see any difference between them nor i didn't understand your question completely

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am afraid it hasn't helped me.

Comment: @webelf000 if you didn't solved your issue, explain it to me so i can help

Comment: I want to make the layout size 30x10mm on the screen, but its size is a little bigger than I want. And I can't calculate DP size correctly.